# How can I Add Audio Player in iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio

I want to add audio player in my app.I have no idea about it.
I want to play songs and make playlist also...how can i do this?

Comment: try reading some documentation

Comment: But I am having no idea what should I refer?

Comment: try searching for AV.foundation in the Apple developer website

Comment: My question is--can I run my application without simulator?I have created app but I am having warnings(not errors)and the app is not working....so,what you think....is it simulator prob?should I use device for this?help me please..

Answer (score 0):

You can find tutorial from the following link:-
http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

or

http://psychicparrotgames.com/?p=33

or

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/abPlayer_iPhone.aspx

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

go through following links, it will help you -
http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

Answer (score 0):

do as below.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

NSString *musicFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *musicURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```